# How to recognized message sending failed if the gsm modem doesn't have load or signal Using C# + Serial Port and AT Commands

Tags: c#

Can you help me to recognized sending message failed? I already handle message send and i don't know how to handle that kind of thing. So anyone know how to handle message sending failed if there's no load or signal a GSM modem? Here is my code:

```
using System.IO.Ports;
public partial class Form1 : Form
{   
    SerialPort sp = New SerialPort();

    //Get the serial port data    
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
    sp.PortName = "COM15";
        sp.BaudRate = 9600;
        sp.Parity = Parity.None;
        sp.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        sp.DataBits = 8;
        sp.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend;
        sp.DtrEnable = True;
        sp.RtsEnable = True;
        sp.NewLine = Environment.NewLine;
    }

    //Send Message
    //MsgBox is a customized message box
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    string message = "";
    message = textbox1.Text;

        sp.Open();
        if (sp.IsOpen())
        {
            //Already handle the sent message with this code.
        sp.Write("AT" + Environment.NewLine);
            sp.Write("AT+CMGF=1" + Environment.NewLine);
            sp.Write("AT+CMGS=" + (char)(34) + TextBox1.Text + (char)(34) + Environment.NewLine);
            sp.Write(message + (char)(26));
            MsgBox("Sent");
        }
        else 
        {
        MsgBox("Port not available");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to attach an event handler to the serial port that fires on data receive.

```
// On initializing the serial port add:
sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived);

// additionally add this eventhandler method
private void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    // contains the reply of your GSM Modem (Maybe with the echoed input you've send)
    string received = ((SerialPort)sender).ReadExisting();
}
```

Hope this helps

Thomas

Comment: I will try this when i got home :). Thanks thomas.

Comment: i doesn't work thomas but thanks anyway. it prompt that i send message even though i dont have signal or load. thanks :)

Comment: Be aware that depending on the gsm you are using, it will Support commands or not. Especially if you are using an old mobile, they are often tricky and badly implemented/restricted.